# Unable to move fast between config files and manuals

Tags: emacs, manuals, manpage

Man's manual have the following

> Specify the configuration file to use; the default is
>   **/private/etc/man.conf**.  (See
>   man.conf(5).)

The PATH is in bold for /private/etc/man.conf in man. It suggests me that it could be a hyperlink to the file. It would be cool to have a Emacs-like moving in man.

I have not succeeded to enter the file directly from man's manual.

**How can you go the file directly from man's manual** without doing the following in man?

```
Ctrl-Z
emacs /private/etc/man.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that I understand your question.

You can view the man pages in Emacs:

```
M-x man man
```

And from within the man page that comes up, with the point on the path in bold.

```
M-x find-file-at-point
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Emacs is clearly superior to the default man in reading manuals.